# Where does a std::vector allocate its memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, vector

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void sub(vector<int>& vec) {
    vec.push_back(5);
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vec(4,0);
    sub(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming "vec" has no space left to store the 5 in the "sub" function, where does it allocate new memory?

In the stack frame of the sub function? In that case the 5 would be deleted at the end of the sub function. But the stack frame of the main function can't grow, as the stack frame of the sub function lies on top of the stack at that moment.
Does a std::vector allocate memory for its elements on the heap?
But how does it free that heap memory?
If it's a local vector on the stack, the stack frame of a function including the vector is deleted in the end without signaling the vector that it will be deleted?

Comment: You might want to look at STL allocators.

Comment: `sub(vector<int>& vec)` called as `sub(vec)` would be definitely easier to read ;)

Comment: **It allocates memory at Heap**
[std::vector Implementation](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60484/stl-vector-implementation)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> Does a std::vector allocate memory for its elements on the heap?

Yes. Or more accurately it allocates based on the allocator you pass in at construction. You didn't specify one, so you get the default allocator. By default, this will be [the heap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/allocate/).

> But how does it free that heap memory?

Through its [destructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_%28computer_programming%29#In_C.2B.2B) when it goes out of scope. (Note that a *pointer* to a vector going out of scope won't trigger the destructor). But if you had passed by value to `sub` you'd construct (and later destruct) a new copy. 5 would then get pushed back onto that copy, the copy would be cleaned up, and the vector in `main` would be untouched.

Comment: I didn't see the http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/allocate/ page mentioned anything about default allocation on heap?

Answer (score 21):

All containers in the STL are parameterized with template arguments, usually the last argument is called `A` or `Allocator` and defaults to `std::allocator<...>` where `...` represents the type of the value stored within the container.

The `Allocator` is a class that is used to provide memory and build/destroy the elements in this memory area. It can allocate memory from a pool or directly from the heap, whichever you build the allocator from. By default the `std::allocator<T>` is a simple wrapper around `::operator new` and will thus allocate memory on the heap as you inferred.

The memory is allocated on demand, and is deallocated at the very least when the `vector`'s destructor is called. C++11 introduces `shrink_to_fit` to release memory sooner too. Finally, when the vector outgrow its current capacity, a new (larger) allocation is made, the objects are moved to it, and the old allocation is released.

As will all local variables, the destructor is called when executed reaches the end of the scope it has been declared into. So, before the function is exited, the vector destructor is called, and only afterward does the stack shrinks and control returns to the caller.

Answer (score 3):

Also note that your vector (`vec`) is object itself. It resides on the stack and when this object goes out of scope (which is end of `main` in your case), it is destructed. Memory for elements is allocated during initialization of this object and released with its destruction, which is a lovely example of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom, since the resource management of elements is tied to the lifespan of vector object.

Answer (score 0):

Because you gave sub the adress of the vector in the heap, it will allocate in the heap. If there's no space left, exception should be thrown.

Comment: There is absolutely no link between a vector on the heap, and it allocating it's memory on the heap.

Comment: The vector isn't on "the heap", whatever that may be. It is in `main`'s stack.

Comment: It doesn't matter wether you allocate a vector on the stack or on the heap, the default implementation will always allocate it's memory on the heap.

Comment: at least that was what I wanted to say. considering I did not say it accurately enough. my fault!