# vector is throwing bad_alloc

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, stdvector, bad-alloc

I have the following code that is throwing a `std::bad_alloc` exception:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> myVector(nlines);
    for(int i = 0; i < nlines; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            std::vector<double> iVector(ncolumns);
            myVector[i] = iVector;
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            /* catches a bad_alloc here */
        }
    }
}
```

This code seems to work when `nlines` is about 500,000 (`ncolumns` will usually be less than 10) but when I tried this on a full sized data set where `nlines` = 2,600,000 I get the bad_alloc exception.

I have 12 GB of memory and looking at my memory useage when running the program it goes from 28% (before starting) up to 42% (when the exception is thrown).  So it looks like I still have memory available.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366497/340045) which says that vectors allocate their memory on the heap.  According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944893/340045), which links to [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/heap-set-heap-size) I can set the amount of heap (in bytes) that my code can use.  Initially the Heap Commit Size and Heap Reserve Size were blank.  When I put in values of 2000000000 (2 GB) I still get the same problem.

To make things a little more interesting, this C++ code (not CLI) is being called using an interop from a C#.NET application.  The modifications to the Heap Commit Size and Heap Reserve Size were set on the C++ project.  I don't know if I also need to set these on the .NET projects or how I would do this.

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: This would be a more efficient way to create your 2d vector. `std::vector<std::vector<double>> myVector(nlines, std::vector<double>(nlines));`

Comment: @NeilKirk yes I had this already, but I commented it out because I was getting an exception and I wanted to see how many elements were being created before the `bad_alloc`.  I am getting to `i = 1960469`.

Comment: Are you building 32-bit or 64-bit exe?

Comment: @NeilKirk For the C++ project, under the Linker settings, it says `Target Machine = MachineX86 (/MACHINE:X86)`.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @NeilKirk: Whether the two are equivalent will depend on what his `catch` block does.

Comment: That's a 32-bit build. It's limited to 2-4gb memory depending on precise settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Neil Kirk points out, a 32-bit process is limited to 2GB of memory as stated in [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx).  This is true for unmanned and managed applications.

There are many SO questions about this, for example I have found these:

[How much memory can a 32 bit process access on a 64 bit operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/639540/340045)

[The maximum amount of memory any single process on Windows can address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11891593/340045)

[Set Maximum Memory Usage C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8966639/340045)

In my case I think that the interop between the .NET and the unmanaged code is doing some buffering and so is eating up the available memory.  Ideally I should only have two or three 2D vectors of 2,600,000 x 10 elements (if a double is 8-bytes then this is still less than 1 GB).  I will need to investigate this further.